# Can I target elements with no rendered content using CSS?

Tags: html, css

The `:empty` CSS pseudo-class targets DOM nodes with no children at all.
I'm interested to know if I can target DOM nodes with children, but with no actually rendered content. For example, if all its children (and the children's children etc.) all have `display: none`.

Comment: No, CSS cannot detect where the element has `display: none`. But you can use JS. jQuery for simplifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

Although the children have no rendered content, they are children anyway, so I'd say you can't target them using `:empty` pseudoclass.

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp

Answer (score 0):

If they have inline style then you can select them.

```
<div style="display:none">Test</div>

div[style="display:none"] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```